# Using GZIPOutputStream to send a compressed chunk in java

Tags: java, http, gzipoutputstream

I'm trying to send a compressed HTML file through a java socket but the browser displays an empty HTML file.

The thing is, when I try to send the uncompressed HTML everything works find (yes I do modify the HTTP headers accordingly).

```
private void sendResponse(String headers, String body) throws IOException
{   
    BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(
        this.SOCKET.getOutputStream());
    byte[] byteBody = null;

    // GZIP compression
    if(body != null && this.encoding.contains("gzip"))
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream zipStream = new GZIPOutputStream(byteStream);
        zipStream.write(body.getBytes(this.charset));
        zipStream.flush();
        byteBody = byteStream.toByteArray();
        byteStream.flush();
        byteStream.close();
        zipStream.close();
    }
    else
        byteBody = body.getBytes(this.charset);

    // Sending response
    byte[] msg1 = (Integer.toHexString(byteBody.length) + "\r\n")
        .getBytes(this.charset);
    byte[] msg2 = byteBody;
    byte[] msg3 = ("\r\n" + "0").getBytes(this.charset);

    output.write(headers.getBytes(this.charset));
    output.write(msg1);
    output.write(msg2);
    output.write(msg3);
    output.flush();
    output.close();
}
```

Basically, ***headers*** contains the HTTP headers, and ***body*** the HTML file. The rest seems self explanatory. What could cause such a behavior?

EDIT: The header is generated as such:

```
    headers = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
    headers += "Date: " + WebServer.getServerTime(Calendar.getInstance()) + "\r\n";
    headers += "Content-Type: text/html; charset=" + this.charset + "\r\n";
    headers += "Set-Cookie: sessionID=" + newCookie + "; Max-Age=600\r\n";
    headers += "Connection: close \r\n";
    if(this.encoding.contains("gzip"))
        headers += "Content-Encoding: gzip\r\n";
    headers += "Transfer-Encoding: chunked \r\n";
    headers += "\r\n";
```

Comment: Please show actual headers, both with and without compression enabled. --- Also, why are you using chunked transfer when you know the full size. Just give the length in the header, so you don't have to do that extra chunking stuff.

Comment: @Andreas Added the headers. Using chunked transfer is part of the assignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that a [`GZIPOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) isn't complete until the [`finish()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html#finish--) method has been called.

It is automatically called when you `close()` the stream.

Since you are calling `byteStream.toByteArray()` *before* that has happened, you're not getting complete data.

Also, you don't need to call `flush()` since that is also automatically done when you call `close()`. And closing the `GZIPOutputStream` automatically closes the underlying stream(s) (i.e. the `ByteArrayOutputStream`).

So, you code should be:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream zipStream = new GZIPOutputStream(byteStream);
zipStream.write(body.getBytes(this.charset));
zipStream.close();
byteBody = byteStream.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple test class should show you where the problem is:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

public class GZipTest {

    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);

        gzos.write("some data".getBytes());
        System.out.println("baos before gzip flush: " + baos.size());
        gzos.flush();
        System.out.println("baos after gzip flush: " + baos.size());
        gzos.close();
        System.out.println("baos after gzip close: " + baos.size());
    }
}
```

This leads to the following output:

```
baos before gzip flush: 10
baos after gzip flush: 10
baos after gzip close: 29
```

You're closing your `GZIPOutputStream` after building you body data, so the browser receives incomplete GZIP-data and therefor can't decompress it.

Comment: You have to call `close()` (or `finish()`) on the `GZIPOutputStream`. Since `close()` on a `ByteArrayOutputStream` is a no-op, nothing gets truncated.

Comment: @Lothar I would thus need to wrap my BufferedOutputStream with GZIPOutputStream to make it work or am I missing something? This would be a problem because I plan to send the HTML file in many chunks and I need to specify their size (or am I missing something there too?).

Comment: @Andreas That's what I'm doing in my test class. So I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: @Gogol31 You can write a part of the body data to the `GZIPOutputStream` and call the `ByteArrayOutputStream`'s `toByteArray`-method to get a block of data. Put the CTE-length-info in front and send it onto the wire. Then you call `reset` on your `ByteArrayOutputStream` and repeat until you reach the end of your body data.

Comment: @Lothar Well it does not seem to work in the particular case where I write the whole body data, that is what I did in the post but with taking what you wrote in your first post into account.